# Examples of Websites built using Spring, Play Framework, Struts

Tags: java, spring, struts, playframework

I am a beginner in Java and going to build a webapp that allows developers to work online on their projects. Something of the sort of bitbucket or github. I have developed sites using PHP and moving away from it.

I was suggested that I should go with Spring Framework as it has a good learning curve and that it will probably look good on my CV if I have worked with Spring rather than Struts or Play Framework.

I tried to find examples of websites built using Spring/Struts/Playframework , but couldn't find any. eg, "Top 50 Ruby on Rails websites" does return appreciable results on Google, but the same is not the case with Spring or Struts or Play Framework. So, can anyone give me some examples of websites/webapps built using Spring/Struts/Playframework?

Also, can someone suggest me other technologies apart from the ones mentioned above that can be used with Java for web development. My project group is finalising on Spring unless we find something else that's equally well-known, easy, and heavy on the CV.

P.S.: I am a college student in final year of graduation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've helped me immensely by asking this question ^_^ I was about to ask this same question and would have to wait for a response that isn't 'google it'

Answer (score 10):

Here's a [list of sites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_Framework#Usage) powered by Playframework.

Answer (score 1):

You can find Struts examples [here](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/PoweredBy)